# Netty readBytes reference counting

Tags: java, netty

I have code that looks something like this:

```
void decodeFragment(ByteBuf fragment) {
    fragment.readByte();
    ...
}

void decodeMessage(ByteBuf buf) {
    buf.readByte(); // header
    ...
    decodeFragment(buf.readBytes(20));
}
```

As far as I understand, new buffer from `readBytes` will have its own reference counting and I need to take care of it. Is there any alternative if I know that I won't need fragment for longer than the original buffer? Maybe `readSlice` is what I'm looking for? Documentation is not very clear.

Another related question. If I create `Unpooled.wrappedBuffer` do I need to take care of reference counting as well? What about `Unpooled.copiedBuffer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want need an extra reference-count and can share or want to share the underlying storage `slice` or `readSlice` is the methods you are looking for.

And yes even for `wrappdBuffer` and `copiedBuffer` you will need to take care of releasing the buffer.

Comment: If I make a `wrappedBuffer` from `ByteBuf` do they share reference count or it's manager separately?

Comment: They share it... that said I guess we should deprecate this method as its confusing and you should just use `buffer.slice()`

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to combine several `ByteBuf` objects into one? I can do it with `wrappedBuffer`.

Comment: Yes or allocate a `CompositeByteBuf`